# Project Based Calculus II

Tags: calculus

[image]![How do I do this problem? I thought this was the correct answer

THoughts?

Thanks guys!][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wo10.png)

Comment: A point consists of two numbers, not a single one in the thousands.

Comment: Also, one needs to take a square root of $(1+y'(x))^2$ for the arc length formula.

Answer (score 1):

Using Pythagoras' theorem, the length of the short piece of curve between $x$ and $x+dx$ is

$$\sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx $$

And the whole curve length is simply

$$\int_{-3}^{3}\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx = \int_{-3}^{3}\sqrt{1 + \left(24x^3+1\right)^2}dx$$